# Render a 3D model (hair) with semi-transparent texture in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, scnmaterial

I'm trying to render a 3D model in SceneKit but it looks incorrect.
For example this [model](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EZu1RQ2OmxvHRMzT1Tca6IndOXW3Z5S8) (it's an SCN file with texture and you can reproduce it in your Xcode):

In Xcode Scene Editor it is rendered like this:

```
Transparency -> Mode -> Dual Layer
Double Sided = true
```

[image]

If I turn off the "Write depth" option, it will look like this: 
But there are also some issues because it I see only "the lowest layer" of haircut.

[image]

I think this should be possible. How to do it right?

Answer (score 3):

The reason that in your 3D model some strands of hair popped out when viewed from different angles is quite usual for SceneKit: your model has semi-transparent material that SceneKit can't render properly due to some inner [engine rendering techniques (time 49:35)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/604/?time=2900) applied to depth buffer.

In order to deal with this problem there are two solutions:

**Solution 1**:

Your 3D model must have a completely opaque texture (without semi-transparent parts at all). In that case use `.dualLayer` property.

[image]

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Hair.scn")!
let hair = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "MDL_OBJ", recursively: true)!

hair.geometry?.firstMaterial?.transparencyMode = SCNTransparencyMode.dualLayer
```

**Solution 2**:

Strands of hair mustn't be a mono-geometry but must be a compound geometry (consisted of several geometry layers unified in one group).

[image]

```
hair.geometry?.firstMaterial?.colorBufferWriteMask = SCNColorMask.all
hair.geometry?.firstMaterial?.readsFromDepthBuffer = false
hair.geometry?.firstMaterial?.writesToDepthBuffer = false
hair.geometry?.firstMaterial?.blendMode = SCNBlendMode.alpha
```